# Golang: How to find disk attached to a virtual machine using govmomi?

Tags: go, virtual-machine, virtualization, vsphere, esx

I want to find vmdk files attached to the virtual machine using govmomi. I can find it managed object store, but programmatically not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have vm's managed object `vmMo`

```
vmdks := []string{}
for _, device := range vmMo.Config.Hardware.Device {
    switch disk := device.(type) {
    case *types.VirtualDisk:
        fileName := disk.GetVirtualDevice().Backing.(types.BaseVirtualDeviceFileBackingInfo).GetVirtualDeviceFileBackingInfo().FileName
        vmdks = append(vmdks, fileName)
    }
}
```